# React Bootstrap Card Image not appearing

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the data fetched from an API to be displayed on the screen. For some reason the image is not getting display, though all the other informations are. I tried changing image type from jpg to png but it still doesn't work

Fruits.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Card } from "react-bootstrap";

import { fruitsList } from "../actions/fruitsActions";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

function Fruits() {
  const FruitsList = useSelector((state) => state.FruitList);
  const { fruits, loading, error } = FruitsList;
  console.log(fruits);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fruitsList());
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <h2>Loading ...</h2>
      ) : error ? (
        <h2>{error}</h2>
      ) : (
        <Row>
          {" "}
          {fruits.map((item, index) => (
            <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3} key={index}>
              <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }} className="my-3 p-3" rounded>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.image} />
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{item.name}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    inventore culpa, commodi voluptates libero ullam quam
                    corporis?
                  </Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>

                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Link href="#">Card Link</Card.Link>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Fruits;
```

Comment: console.log your `item.image`. give us what it prints out

Comment: what response is u getting? What's the error.

Comment: if its loading issue try `{item.image && item.image}`

Comment: @Apostolos on doing a console log, i get the following : /images/apple.jpg

Comment: @SwordI I get that broken image mark, the one that shows when the image can't be displayed and I tried {item.image && item.image}, still getting that broken image mark

Comment: ok so you need to prepend the url of your server and your deployed app

Comment: I tried : src=`http://localhost:8000/${item.image}` but it doesn't work also tried src='src=http://localhost:8000/{item.image}', what should be the correct syntax ?

Comment: @Apostolos I tried : src=http://localhost:8000/${item.image} template strings but it doesn't work also tried src='localhost:8000{item.image}', what should be the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that, the server address was omitted so what had to be done was :

```
 <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }} className="my-3 p-3">
                <Card.Img
                  variant="top"
                  src={"http://localhost:8000"+item.image}
                />
                
 </Card>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem on image store link.
If it is in localhost use `http://localhost:3000 + item.image` .
If the folder in server use image storage folder link e.g `http://www.website.com`

```
 const url = http://localhost:3000 or http://www.website.com

  <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }} className="my-3 p-3">
      <Card.Img
         variant="top"
         src={url+item.image}
      />       
  </Card>
```

Hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

<Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />

1. Check value of {item.image}.
2. Open inspect mode go to network and check is it loading your image.

Comment: the value of {item.image} is /images/apple.jpg which I believe is to go in src and the images are loaded when i check the network